# Pattern Builder - фабрика для захардкоженных объектов?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Изучая паттерн Builder я столкнулся с двумя его реализациями. В реализации, в которой объект создается поэтапно, все предельно ясно, она отлично заменяет множество конструкторов. А вот со второй у меня возникло недопонимание.

Пример из Вики:

```
/** "Product" */
 class Pizza {
    private String dough = "";
    private String sauce = "";
    private String topping = "";

    public void setDough(String dough)     { this.dough = dough; }
    public void setSauce(String sauce)     { this.sauce = sauce; }
    public void setTopping(String topping) { this.topping = topping; }
 }


 /** "Abstract Builder" */
 abstract class PizzaBuilder {
    protected Pizza pizza;

    public Pizza getPizza() { return pizza; }
    public void createNewPizzaProduct() { pizza = new Pizza(); }

    public abstract void buildDough();
    public abstract void buildSauce();
    public abstract void buildTopping();
 }

 /** "ConcreteBuilder" */
 class HawaiianPizzaBuilder extends PizzaBuilder {
    public void buildDough()   { pizza.setDough("cross"); }
    public void buildSauce()   { pizza.setSauce("mild"); }
    public void buildTopping() { pizza.setTopping("ham+pineapple"); }
 }

 /** "ConcreteBuilder" */
 class SpicyPizzaBuilder extends PizzaBuilder {
    public void buildDough()   { pizza.setDough("pan baked"); }
    public void buildSauce()   { pizza.setSauce("hot"); }
    public void buildTopping() { pizza.setTopping("pepperoni+salami"); }
 }


 /** "Director" */
 class Waiter {
    private PizzaBuilder pizzaBuilder;

    public void setPizzaBuilder(PizzaBuilder pb) { pizzaBuilder = pb; }
    public Pizza getPizza() { return pizzaBuilder.getPizza(); }

    public void constructPizza() {
       pizzaBuilder.createNewPizzaProduct();
       pizzaBuilder.buildDough();
       pizzaBuilder.buildSauce();
       pizzaBuilder.buildTopping();
    }
 }


 /** A customer ordering a pizza. */
 public class BuilderExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Waiter waiter = new Waiter();
        PizzaBuilder hawaiianPizzaBuilder = new HawaiianPizzaBuilder();
        waiter.setPizzaBuilder(hawaiianPizzaBuilder);
        waiter.constructPizza();

        Pizza pizza = waiter.getPizza();
    }
 }
```

**Неужели для того чтобы создать объект с захардкожеными значениями нужно написать столько лишнего кода?**

Вообщем, вопрос в том имеет ли приемущества такое решение?

Или я могу могу назвать это решение **фабрикой захардкоженных объектов** и больше не пытаться искать в нем смысл. А для себя определить Builder, как было описано в начале, как паттерн позволяющий поэтапно создавать объект.